# Fail to consume SOAP WS with Spring-WS in Spring boot but works from SOAPUI

Tags: spring-boot, soap, spring-ws, siebel

I'm using Spring Boot to consume a SOAP WS which I generate from a WSDL. I added the spring-ws-security so I can pass the user/password as security header as shown in the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    public static final String SIEBEL_ENDPOINT = "http://...";

    @Bean
    public CustomerClient customerClient() {
        CustomerClient client = new CustomerClient();
        client.setDefaultUri(SIEBEL_ENDPOINT);
        client.setWebServiceTemplate(webServiceTemplate(marshaller()));
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller, marshaller);
        template.setDefaultUri(SIEBEL_ENDPOINT);
        ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = new ClientInterceptor[] {new LogHttpHeaderClientInterceptor(), wsSecurityInterceptor()};
        template.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.test.dms.gen");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wsSecurityInterceptor() {
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType(WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("rf_USER");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("rf_USER");
        return wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
    }

}
```

And the service call:

```
public class CustomerClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
 
    public CustomerInfoOutput getCustomerInfo(String vin) {
        ObjectFactory request = new ObjectFactory();
        final CustomerInfoInput custInfoInput = request.createCustomerInfoInput();
        custInfoInput.setVINNumber(vin);


        return (CustomerInfoOutput) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(ClientConfig.SIEBEL_ENDPOINT, custInfoInput);
    }
}
```

everything is well generated, and this logged output:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                   SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-e8f183db-44db-4c0b-90d9-ca57e89225fd">
            <wsse:Username>rf_USER</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">rf_USER</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns3:CustomerInfo_Input xmlns:ns2="http://siebel.com/testdashboard"
                            xmlns:ns3="http://test.com/rf/customerinfo" xmlns:ns4="http://test.com/rf"
                            xmlns:ns5="http://www.siebel.com/xml/IBM%20test%20Dashboard">
        <ns3:VINNumber>123456789</ns3:VINNumber>
    </ns3:CustomerInfo_Input>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

When I send this request using SOAP UI, it works perfectly. But when it's sent using the generated objects from the WSDL, I have this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>There is no active Web Service with operation named
                'http://test.com/rf/customerinfo:CustomerInfo_Input'.(SBL-EAI-04313)
            </faultstring>
            <detail>
                <siebelf:siebdetail xmlns:siebelf="http://www.siebel.com/ws/fault">
                    <siebelf:logfilename>EAIObjMgr_enu_0023_24117286.log</siebelf:logfilename>
                    <siebelf:errorstack>
                        <siebelf:error>
                            <siebelf:errorcode>SBL-EAI-04313</siebelf:errorcode>
                            <siebelf:errorsymbol>IDS_EAI_WS_OP_NOT_FOUND</siebelf:errorsymbol>
                            <siebelf:errormsg>There is no active Web Service with operation named
                                'http://test.com/rf/customerinfo:CustomerInfo_Input'.(SBL-EAI-04313)
                            </siebelf:errormsg>
                        </siebelf:error>
                    </siebelf:errorstack>
                </siebelf:siebdetail>
            </detail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas please?

PS: please don't focus on URIs because I changed them, but the generated request works fine in SOAPUI.

Comment: Can you trace the RAW request going out ? Look for the part which says SOAPAction.

Comment: Thanks @RanjithR: I traced through Wireshark and didn't find it. I added it thrgough WebServiceMessageCallback as mentionned in the wsdl for soap:operation attribute soapAction (document/http://test.com/rf/customerinfo:CustomerInfo) but also it said that There is no active Web Service with operation named as mentionned in the soapAction

Comment: @RanjithR It works! The problem is that spring ws removes from the soapaction "document", and because Siebel is waiting for document or rpc, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the hint of @RanjithR I processed as follow:

I traced the SOAP Call using Wireshark, and I discovered that Spring WS doesn't include the header `SOAPAction`. The following SOF question talks about this, and how to configure it (it sends you to the spring documentation which explains well the thing). [Spring-WS client not setting SOAPAction header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571273/spring-ws-client-not-setting-soapaction-header)

The second thing is that, even if I added the header, it continues to tell me that the endpoint is not sent.

In my WSDL, the SOAPAction is defined as follows:

`<soap:operation soapAction="document/http://test.com/rf/customerinfo:CustomerInfo"></soap:operation>`

And my Spring ws call was like that:

```
return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(ClientConfig.SIEBEL_ENDPOINT,
                customerInfoInput,
                webServiceMessage -> ((SoapMessage)webServiceMessage).setSoapAction("document/http://ripl.com/rforce/customerinfo:CustomerInfo"));
```

In Wireshark, I had:

`SOAPAction: "http://ripl.com/rforce/customerinfo:CustomerInfo"`

But when I trace the same call from SOAP UI I have:
SOAPAction: "document/http://ripl.com/rforce/customerinfo:CustomerInfo"

So I tried to send a string literal as a SOAPAction:

`"\"document/http://ripl.com/rforce/customerinfo:CustomerInfo\"";`
Note the `\"\"` around the action and it works :)

Maybe it can help someone that have to integrate with Jurasik Park systems...

Answer (score 1):

This post saved me a lot of time by pointing me in the right direction. The Action header was not added for me using the method described above, but the following method worked fine:

```
// add action header

final String ActionHeaderName = "Action";
final String ActionHeaderPrefix = "wsa";
final String ActionHeaderNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
final String ActionHeaderContent = "http://example/ActionHeader";
var actionName = soapEnvelope.createName(ActionHeaderName, ActionHeaderPrefix, ActionHeaderNamespace);
var actionHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader().addHeaderElement(actionName);
                                actionHeader.setTextContent(ActionHeaderContent);
```

Thanks a lot @Marouane

Comment: All the pleasure, happy it helped you, stuck in creepy places of SOAP universe